# How to assign multiple colour scales to a dataset in ggplot2; assign different color scale to each column variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to assign different colour scales to my dataset based on the column variable. The dummy code is

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1', 'f1'),
                  var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'),
                  var2 = c(0.006, 0.04, .005, 0, 0.02, 0.05))
```

Instead of an overall colour scale, I want 'a' from var1 to be red to white, 'b'blue to white, and 'c' as purple to white. I have 4000 rows in my actual data, I tried to nest each on top of each other, but failed.. the running is below. Please suggest where do I need to make the changes to get my desired output.

P.S.I know, the var2 will have different high's and lows, if legend is available, great, otherwise I just need to show color differences.

```
ggplot(df1,aes(y = var1, x = ID, fill = var2)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "steelblue", high = "white") +
  ylab("var1") +
  xlab("ID") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(fill = "ABC association")
```

Comment: ggplot2 does not permit multiple scales of a single type (i.e. multiple colour or fill scales). If you really want the desired behavior you will need to play with grobs, grids etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you want each colour scale to take on a gradient between a specific colour and white, you can fake it by assigning a different colour to each `var1` value, and vary the transparency based on var2. Here's an illustration, though of course you can vary the details depending on how you want the results to appear:

**Step 1**. Define the colour for each var1 value.

```
color.scale <- c("a" = "red", "b" = "blue", "c" = "purple")
```

**Step 2**. Scale the range of `var2` values within each `var1` category to a common range.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(var1) %>%
  mutate(var2.alpha = scale(var2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(var1)

> df2
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  ID     var1      var2 var2.alpha
  <fctr> <fctr>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1 a1     a      0.00600      0.707
2 d1     a      0           -0.707
3 b1     b      0.0400       0.707
4 e1     b      0.0200      -0.707
5 c1     c      0.00500     -0.707
6 f1     c      0.0500       0.707
```

**Step 3**. Create your plot. The first white `geom_tile()` provides a "backing" for the coloured tile layer, so that background elements (panel colour, grid lines, etc) don't show up within the tiles.

```
p.plot <- ggplot(df2,
       aes(x = ID, y = var1, fill = var1, alpha = var2.alpha)) +
  geom_tile(fill = "white", alpha = 1) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color.scale) +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0.1, 0.9)) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: p.plot]

**Step 4**. Create a separate plot to serve as the legend.

```
df3 <- df2 %>% group_by(var1) %>% 
  summarise(min = min(var2), max = max(var2)) %>%
  mutate(tile.1 = 0.1, tile.3 = 0.3, tile.5 = 0.5, tile.7 = 0.7, tile.9 = 0.9) %>%
  tidyr::gather(tile, value, -var1, -min, -max)
p.legend <- ggplot(df3, aes(x = value, y = var1, fill = var1, alpha = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = var1), x = -0.1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = min), x = 0.1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = max), x = 0.9, color = "white") +
  ggtitle("ABC association") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-0.2, 1.1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color.scale) +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: p.legend]

**Step 5**. Combine the two, allocating more space to the main plot.

```
cowplot::plot_grid(p.plot, p.legend, 
                   ncol = 1, align = "v", 
                   rel_heights = c(5, 1))
```

[image: combined plot]